# libicui18n.so.55: cannot open shared object file

Tags: 18.04, apt, libreoffice

My libreoffice was fine on Ubuntu 16.04. The problem started after I upgraded to 18.04.

It does not open `calc`. Running it in command-line:

```
libreoffice --calc
/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin: error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.55: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Trying:

```
sudo apt install libreoffice-common
sudo apt install libreoffice-core
sudo apt-get install libicu-dev
```

Does not resolve the problem.

Also:

```
E: Package 'libicu55' has no installation candidate
```

tried

```
sudo apt purge libreoffice
sudo apt autoremove 
sudo apt install libreoffice
```

which did not work either.

It is not just about calc but all libreoffice applications.

Comment: What is your libreoffice version, and how was it installed? is it possible that you are running an (older) version that is not from the Ubuntu repository and was not updated when you went from 16.04 -> 18.04?

Comment: @steeldriver, synaptic shows me that it is `1:6.0.7`. I don't remember how it was installed many years go. It must have been via `apt-get`. It should not matter after you uninstall it then install it again.

Comment: OK but is that the version you're actually running though? what does `libreoffice --version` say?

Comment: @steeldriver, `libreoffice --version` does not even run. It gives the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like there is a problem with the libreoffice. This is a bug to me. The workaround:

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/libicu55_55.1-7_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libicu55_55.1-7_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get -f install
rm libicu55_55.1-7_amd64.deb
```

Then, the problem is resolved.